# TinyMCE issue with Base64 images

Tags: tinymce

Many email clients do not support Base64 images. I use TineyMCE in my app and have had many clients negatively comment on this.

The question is how can I modify TM to not use Base64.

This is the code from TinyMCE used to select an image:

```
`   const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      const file = e.target.files[0];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      
        const id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        const blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        const base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        const blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    input.click();
    }`
```